# $Timeout service for data refreshing not working(Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i've been working  on an application using angularjs and symfony. I was trying to retrieve data on a repetitive basis every 5000 ms, so i resorted to "$timeout" feature to get a real-time data retrieval from server.

Here is my controller code :

```
.controller('clientController', [ '$rootScope','$scope', 'Api' , 'toastr',   
'$window', '$routeParams', '$filter'  , '$timeout',
 function($rootScope,$scope, Api  ,toastr, $window, $routeParams, $filter , 
 $timeout) {

     $rootScope.myVar=true;


 $scope.clients = [];
 var  retrieveItems = function () {

 Api.getAllClients()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log('result', result);
    $scope.clients = result.data;
    $timeout(retrieveItems, 5000);
  }, function (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  });
  };



 ...

}])
```

Here 's the vue code :

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="editable-datatable">
                           <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                     <th>tel</th>
                                     <th>Actions</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="client in clients" id="1" class="gradeX">
                                    <td>{{client.username}}</td>
                                    <td>{{client.email}}</td>
                                   <td>{{client.tel}}</td>

                                     <td  collapse=3>

                                                 <a style="border: 1px solid rgba(10, 6, 6, 0.25); padding: 4px;" ng-href="#!/client/{{client.id}}" ng-click="ClientDetailsController()">
                                                   <i class="icon-eye-open"></i> Details 
         </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;



<span style="margin-left: 10px"><a  data-toggle="modal" href  data 
target="#exampleModal" ng-click="setID(client.id)" >
                       <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> Delete
                                                  </a></span>

                                        </td>


                                </tr>


                            </tbody>

                        </table>
```

My problem is that whenever i remove the "retrieveItems" function everything works just fine. I get all the clients but when to add the timeout service so i can refresh the registered clients every 5 seconds... The clients won't load on the vue but no errors in the error section. Would someone please enlighten me to what exactly the problem might be ..any other suggestions to make real time retrieval functional. Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think you have to add $scope.$apply().

Comment: Hi!!  thanks a lot  for your reply..would you please tell me where exactly do i have to put it ?

Comment: your code looks ok, maybe you always get the same data

Answer (score 2):

To get the data every 5000 ms you should use

> $interval service [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$interval)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you need to use $interval for repetitive  calls. 
Secondly You have to assign scope values inside scope of angular not in pure functions like

```
 var  retrieveItems = function () { ... }
```

Try using,

```
 $scope.retrieveItems = function () {...}

I think this wont be asking to $scope.apply()
```